# Additional cancellation fee on a nonrefundable plane ticket: is there any disadvantage to just not showing up?

Tags: cancellations, fees-and-charges

I bought a ticket through justfly.com, but I might need to cancel it now. I was informed that the ticket is nonrefundable, which is fine--I expected this. I was also told that there would be an additional cancellation fee. This seems strange to me. Is there any reason that I couldn't just not cancel the ticket to avoid the fee, and then simply not show up for my flight?

Comment: It appears justfly.com has really bad customer service and ratings at the Better Business Bureau. If you used a credit card to purchase it, just call the credit card company and notify them not to process any charges from justfly.com. You can also ask your credit card company to cancel your card and send you a card with a different number. That ends matters right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-refundable does not mean non-changeable.  If there is a cancellation fee or a change fee stated for the ticket, that usually means you have a changeable ticket.

In your case canceling the booking should result in the airfare you paid minus the cancellation fee becoming a credit that you can use for a future ticket on that airline (often with a time limit for use).

I don't think justfly.com can charge an additional fee on top of the airfare you paid.